# What is the source of uncomputability?

Tags: computability

I know there may be no definitive answer to theses question, since they are rather broad and opinion based.

I have a solid CS background and want to continue (post)graduate study research in CS. In particular, I am interested in questions like "*What is source of uncomputability in CS/Math?*", "*The reason behind why DFA is less powerful than PDA*". In other words these questions are closer to the limits of formal systems.

I would be glad if someone could give me some reference, as from which topics to star. By the way, I have found last the book by R. Soare, *Computability Theory and Applications: The Art of Classical Computability*, very interesting, could I start from this book?

Comment: One source of uncomputability is the lack of continuity. In some sense, every computable function is continuous (the topology depends on the model of computation). [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166629/computability-continuity-and-constructivism) has some links on the subject.

Comment: @AmauryPouly Thanks! Do you think this book by R. Soare is a good starting point? I have a good knowledge on set theory (cardinal/ordinal numbers,..etc) I think I will need also take a course on real analysis, what do you think?

Comment: If you are interested in uncomputability and formal systems, I strongly suggest you take a course on real analysis and algebra. Unfortunately I do not know that book but looking at the preface it sounds like it contains interesting material. Depending on your background and interest, I have heard that the book Theory of Computation, by Michael Sipser, provides a good introduction to the topic of computability.